# Is there an R function to count strings by re-arranging the table

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe similar to the one below:

```
study_name = c("ESF", "ESF", "ESF","AAB" )
results= c("alive", "alive", "dead", "dead")

df1 = data_frame(study_name,results, place)
```

I was trying to use `tidyverse` and `groupby` the `study_name` and then count `alive` and `dead` but it didn't work. This is what I tried to do:

```
df1 <- m_df %>% 
  group_by(study_name) %>% 
  summarise(n_alive=n_distinct("alive"),
            n_dead=n_distinct("dead"))
```

This is how I wanted the re-arrangement and count to be as in `df2`

```
alive= c(2, 0)
study_name = c("ESF","AAB" )
dead= c(1, 1)

df2 =data_frame(study_name, alive, dead)
```

Comment: *Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : object 'place' not found*.

Comment: Is `table(df1[1:2])` what you want?

Comment: Or `df1 %>% group_by(study_name) %>% summarise(alive = sum(results == 'alive'),
            dead = sum(results == 'dead'))` in `dplyr` but surely there's a dupe for that

Comment: Or `df1 %>% count(study_name, results) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = results, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)`

Comment: Or `df1 %>% select(study_name, results) %>% table %>% as.tibble`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. `df1 %>% group_by(study_name) %>% summarise(alive = sum(results == 'alive'), dead = sum(results == 'dead'))` worked very well. Thanks again